# Inserting a JS variable within a Django template tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, django-templates

This one is a bit tricky for me. I've thus-far resorted to query parameters instead a variable within the `{% url %}` tag, but I've just got to ask if it's doable:

I'd like to include a JS variable within my template tag. For example:

```
...
var foo = $(this).attr('title');
$('#bar').load("{% url app.views.view foo %}");
...
```

Can it be done?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Javascript variable in Django Template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217455/access-javascript-variable-in-django-template)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not doable.  The HTML (and Javascript) are already rendered and served to the client by the time the Javascript is evaluated.

You need some other approach, like (as you mentioned) query parameters:

```
var foo = $(this).attr('title');
$('#bar').load("{% url app.views.view %}?foo=" + foo);
```

Comment: Most unfortunate, but as I suspected. Sure would be nice.