# Access Javascript variable in Django Template

Tags: javascript, python, django

Is there is any way to access `javascript` variable in `Django` template `tags` ?
Can i do something like this ,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
    <script>
        var javascriptvar=0;
    </script>
    {% if javascriptvar==0 %}
         do this
    {% else %}
         do this
    {% endif %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not like that. Python and JavaScript execute at two totally different times. What are you trying to do and why? You could use AJAX, but it might be overkill

Comment: @lan , Actually i am trying to truncate some text using django template tag , And this processing is based on some javascript variable.

Comment: @Nishant Django & JavaScript share different execution environment Server and Client respectively ... what you are trying to do is not correct. I will suggest if javascriptvar is so obvious use it on templates itselft

Comment: How is the JS variable being set and why are you trying to base your Django logic on it?

Comment: Depends what u want to achieve. If just need to truncate text on client side u dont need django tag at all. If u need to truncate and save truncated text on server then use ajax

Comment: @lan , it is based upon calculations based on some `django` template variable. I think i have to calculate this value of `javascript` variable in views and then render it to template and then process it as suggested by @Anil.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, the Django template is compiled server side. It is then sent to the client where their browser executes the JavaScript. Nothing that is changed by the JavaScript executing on the client browser can have an affect on the template. It's too late at that point.

However the JavaScript could do something like make another request from the server for more information. Or you could just pre-compute the value on the server before you send it to the client. If you are more explicit about what you are trying to do we should be able to help.

You can of course use Django templates to set JavaScript variables.

```
<script>
    var myVar = '{{ py_var }}';
</script>
```