# Inner HTML with Django tamplate if statement usig Js variable

Tags: javascript, django, jinja2, innerhtml

I'm really new in JavaScript and I have a question:
I need to add  inside an inner Html, a Django template if statement that uses a JavaScript variable to compare (in this case the variable is event_id)

I have tried a lot of alternatives after hours and also I have searched with no success.

This is my JS code.

```js
eventClick: function (info) {
                var event_id = info.event.id;
                 $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('show');
                selected_group_member.innerHTML = `
                {% for reservation in reservations_api %}
                {% if reservation.id == ${event_id} %}
                <option value="1" selected>{{reservation.id}}</option>
                {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
                `;
                }
```

with this option, I'm getting this error:
`Could not parse the remainder: '${event_id}' from '${event_id}'`

and if I change it for `{% if reservation.id ==`  + event_id + `%}`, I'm getting this error: `Could not parse the remainder: '`' from '`'`

So, is that possible to do? Do you know how could it work please !!!
I really don't know how to solve it, I really appreciate your help
thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access Javascript variable in Django Template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22217455/access-javascript-variable-in-django-template)

Comment: Unfortunately you can't do this - the Django templates are executed on the server side, well before the javascript executes. While I'm not exactly sure what you're trying to do, I think it's probably possible using only javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this could work for you:

```
eventClick: function (info) {
  const reservations = '{{ reservations_api | safe }}';
  var event_id = info.event.id;
  $('#exampleModalToggle').modal('show');

  let innerHtml = '';
  reservations.forEach((reservation) => {
    if (reservation.id == event_id)
      innerHtml += `<option value="1" selected>${reservation.id}</option>`;
  });

  selected_group_member.innerHTML = innerHtml
}
```

First of all you create a new javascript variable (called `reservations`), then you concatenate the desired `<option>` string into another variable (`innerHtml`). Finally you set the `innerHtml` to your `selected_group_member`.

**Update**

Added `| safe` template tag https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#safe as discovered in comments.

Comment: Thanks a looot for your help! it seems a really nice solution :), I tried but I'm getting this error : `Uncaught TypeError: reservations.forEach is not a function`, maybe is because the "eventClick" is a method from fullcalendar library and maybe disable the "forEach", but I'm not sure, I really don't know

Comment: ohh I get it :) with the safe argument in ` {{ reservations_api | safe }};` :D thanks a lot :)